# What are the "Window animation scale", "Transition animation scale" and "Animator duration scale" settings in android developer settings?

Tags: settings, developer-options

I have seen many posts suggesting to turn them off, i have them turned off and notice quicker transitions, no animations, etc. But in some places it is weird to see no animation.

I googled the terms to try to find what they meant, but could only find the above suggestions. Could someone explain what effects each setting has?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/q/81529/131553

Answer (score 3):

All 3 of these are set to 1.0× by default ⁠;  you don't need to turn them off, just cut the values in half and set them all to 0.5 for noticeable snappier performance.

As for what each one does specifically and using my Galaxy S8+ to test them ⁠᎓

**Window animation scale** controls *pop-up window opening and closing animation speed,* such as the pop-up you get with the various speeds you can choose when you select this option.

**Transition animation scale** controls *app window opening and closing animation speed,*

**Animator duration scale** controls *app switching animation speed.*

If you use your phone's stock launcher, one of these⁠ ⁠— ⁠likely the middle one ⁠— ⁠will also affect homescreen-to-homescreen transition animation speed ⁠;  on my phone I use Nova Launcher and homescreen animation speed is adjustable within Nova itself, and is unaffected by any of the above developer options.